# Outlook Redemption - Change the default inbox while reading emails

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I'm trying to read a different Inbox for another account with one user. So if I'm user Bob and I have access to mailboxes `bob@domain.com`and`alerts@domain.com` I want to use Outlook Redemptions to read the alerts@domain.com mailbox.

Currently I have it set up like so:

```
 rdoDefaultFolders olFolderInbox = rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox;

                Session = new RDOSession();
                RDOFolder objFolder;

                Session.LogonExchangeMailbox(outLookUser, outLookServer);
                objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
```

But this gives me the default inbox folder for bob@domain.com. I need the other inbox for alerts@domain.com.

However I want something like

```
Session.LogonExchangeMailbox(outLookUser, outLookServer, outLookMailBox)
```

where outLookMailBox is something like the mailbox name or another inbox folder name in my current outlook session.

I'm hoping someone out there knows what I'm talking about because I've been at this for hours!

Comment: Question currently do you pass a user and login ? doesn't outlook look at it's MailBox on a user profile basis do you have to create a separate user..? if not I can post an example of how I would do it if you like

Comment: any final solution with full source code about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well call me dumb but it turns out when you call `Session.LogonExchangeMailbox(outLookUser, outLookServer, outLookMailBox)`  you can actually use a `mailbox domain OR a username`. The documentation was quite hard to find but eventually found it here: 
http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm